# How to sort a specific date-time column in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I want to sort a specific column on a file by time. The type is the following: 2022-08-25_TIME_HERE.

Date its "fixed", only the time needs sorting by time.

So for example we have the following part from the file (fifth column on file):

```
2022-08-25_22:55:01
2022-08-25_20:23:24
2022-08-25_22:53:07
2022-08-25_21:53:30
2022-08-25_20:23:33
2022-08-25_20:22:14
```

What I want after sorting:

```
2022-08-25_20:22:14
2022-08-25_20:23:24
2022-08-25_20:23:33
2022-08-25_21:53:30
2022-08-25_22:53:07
2022-08-25_22:55:01
```

I have tried a lot of commands such as awk, perl, sed but I am not getting the desired result. The difficulty is in the fixed part of the column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `sort -k5 file` ?

Comment: please update the question with some of your (`awk/perl/sed`) code attempts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perl` works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# Sort timestamps

use 5.12.10;
use Time::Piece;

my $fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S';
my @t;
while( <DATA> ){
    if( $_ !~ m@\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}@ ){
        say STDERR "Invalid format $_";
        next
    }
    chop;  # Delete newline
    push @t, Time::Piece->strptime($_, $fmt);
}

say $_->strftime($fmt) foreach sort @t;

__DATA__
2022-08-25_22:55:01
2022-08-25_20:23:24
2022-08-25_22:53:07
2022-08-25_21:53:30
2022-08-25_20:23:33
2022-08-25_20:22:14
```

To put that in a one-liner, you could do:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lnE 'eval { push @t, Time::Piece->strptime($_,"'$fmt'") } or say "Invalid input: $_" } { say $_->strftime("'$fmt'") foreach sort @t' input-file
```

Comment: I tried it, it works as I want, but how do I adjust it to work with the following file format:

`w1: { version: 1.0.0, worker_id: 6374526, worker_started: 2022-08-25_22:56:02 }`

Comment: If the file is small enough (ie, fits easily in memory) just parse the file into a dict and sort on the date.  There are numerous similar examples available.

Comment: eg: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=773475 Just change the sort function to compare dates.